# PHP - Sending a javascript variable over to a .PHP script

Tags: php, javascript

So, not entirely sure if this is correct, but, here is my php doc: connect.php

```
  <?php
mysql_connect("timereliefusers.db.8956371.hostedresource.com", "timereliefusers", "User1!db") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timereliefusers") or die (mysql_error());


    $choice =(int) $_GET["choice"];

    switch ($choice) {
        case 1:
        mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice1 = choice1 + 1");
        break;
        case 2:
        mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice2 = choice2 + 1");
        break;
        case 3:
        mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice3 = choice3 + 1");
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Then, I send an AJAX request to the php doc here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var choice = 0;

    $("#s1main div").click(function(){
        $("#s1main div").removeClass("buttonclicked");
        $(this).addClass("buttonclicked");

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "choice1"){
            choice = 1;
        }

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "choice2"){
            choice = 2;
        }

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "choice3"){
            choice = 3;
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "connect.php?choice=" + choice, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        alert("Variables passed");          

    });
```

Please tell me of any errors concerning these two documents, thank you - Chris

***NOTE: This doesn't get past the alert("variables passed"); for some odd reason, could someone explain as to why that happens? There must be something wrong with the AJAX call.***

Comment: You might want to remove your username and password for the DB from this so others can't see it

Comment: Assuming you're using `jQuery` in your js script, why don't you use `$.get` or `$.ajax` instead of `xmlhttp`?

Comment: xmlhttp does the exact same thing, if I were to use $.get, how would I be passing the variable?

Comment: @ChrisCates what do you mean never gets passed the alert? That is the last thing in your script... Is it never alerting?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never send choice to your script...you should do something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("db.host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timereliefusers") or die (mysql_error());


$choice = (int) $_GET["choice"];

switch ($choice) {
    case 1:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice1 = choice1 + 1");
    break;
    case 2:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll1 set choice2 = choice2 + 1");
    break;
    case 3:
    mysql_query("UPDATE poll3 set choice3 = choice3 + 1");
    break;
}
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    if (choice != 0) {
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "connect.php?choice=" + choice, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    });
```

Comment: notice `$choice = (int) $choice` this will keep you from having someone sneak a string by, I would have usually `mysql_real_escape_stiring()` but since its just numbers (int) will work fine. Also, notice the javascript, `"connect.php?choice=" + choice`

Comment: Could you edit out his connection info please - he's done it in the main post now so it's just left on display here :)

Comment: Great thanks, testing it on my server now. Knew I was missing something when passing variables, this should do the trick.

Comment: I did some workarounds, take a look at the original post to check for any errors. Thank you.